# select event doesn't fire when right click on primefaces treenode

Tags: jsf, select, primefaces, tree, contextmenu

I have jsf page :

```
<p:contextMenu for="treeProfileSetEvent"
                                   nodeType="PROFILESET">
                        <p:menuitem value="#{lang['common.button.add']}" 
                                    icon="ui-icon-plus"
                                    update="@([id$=editPanel_event])"
                                    actionListener="#{profileSetEventController.prepareAdd()}">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSetEventController.formStatus}" value="#{vpcrfConst.BTN_ADD}" />
                        </p:menuitem>                     
                        <p:menuitem value="#{lang['common.button.delete']}" 
                                    icon="ui-icon-close"
                                    update="@([id$=btnPanel]) @([id$=treeProfileSetEvent]) @([id$=msgInfo])" 
                                    actionListener="#{profileSetEventController.prepareDelete()}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('deleteDialog').show()">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSetEventController.formStatus}" 
                                                         value="#{vpcrfConst.BTN_DELETE}" />                            
                        </p:menuitem>                                          
                    </p:contextMenu>
                    <p:contextMenu for="treeProfileSetEvent"
                                   nodeType="PARENT">   
                        <p:menuitem value="#{lang['common.button.edit']}" 
                                    icon="ui-icon-pencil"                                    
                                    update="@([id$=editPanel_profileSetEvent])"
                                    actionListener="#{profileSetEventController.prepareEdit()}">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSetEventController.formStatus}" 
                                                         value="#{vpcrfConst.BTN_EDIT}" />
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem value="#{lang['common.button.delete']}" 
                                    icon="ui-icon-close"
                                    update="@([id$=btnPanel]) @([id$=treeProfileSetEvent]) @([id$=msgInfo])" 
                                    actionListener="#{profileSetEventController.prepareDelete()}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('deleteDialog').show()">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSetEventController.formStatus}" 
                                                         value="#{vpcrfConst.BTN_DELETE}" />                            
                        </p:menuitem>                                          
                    </p:contextMenu>
                    <p:contextMenu for="treeProfileSetEvent"                                  
                                   nodeType="PARENT_HAS_CHILD">
                        <p:menuitem value="#{lang['common.button.delete']}" 
                                    icon="ui-icon-close"
                                    ajax="true"
                                    update="@([id$=btnPanel]) @([id$=treeProfileSetEvent]) @([id$=msgInfo])" 
                                    actionListener="#{profileSetEventController.prepareDelete()}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('deleteDialog').show()">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSetEventController.formStatus}" 
                                                         value="#{vpcrfConst.BTN_DELETE}" />                            
                        </p:menuitem>                                          
                    </p:contextMenu>
                    <p:contextMenu for="treeProfileSetEvent"
                                   nodeType="CHILD">    
                        <p:menuitem value="#{lang['common.button.edit']}" 
                                    icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                                    update="@([id$=editPanel_profileSetEvent])"
                                    actionListener="#{profileSetEventController.prepareEdit()}">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSetEventController.formStatus}" 
                                                         value="#{vpcrfConst.BTN_EDIT}" />
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem value="#{lang['common.button.delete']}" 
                                    icon="ui-icon-close"
                                    update="@([id$=btnPanel]) @([id$=treeProfileSetEvent]) @([id$=msgInfo])" 
                                    actionListener="#{profileSetEventController.prepareDelete()}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('deleteDialog').show()">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileSetEventController.formStatus}" 
                                                         value="#{vpcrfConst.BTN_DELETE}" />                            
                        </p:menuitem>                                          
                    </p:contextMenu>
                    <p:tree id="treeProfileSetEvent"
                            value="#{profileSetEventController.root}"
                            selection="#{profileSetEventController.selectedNode}"
                            dynamic="true"                            
                            selectionMode="single"   
                            animate="true"
                            cache="true"
                            var="ps"
                            styleClass="vpcrf-tree-50pc">
                        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{profileSetEventController.onNodeSelectListener}" update="@([id$=btnPanel]) @([id$=dlgProfileSetEvent])" />
                        <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{profileSetEventController.onNodeExpandListener}" update="@([id$=btnPanel]) @([id$=dlgProfileSetEvent])" />
                        <p:treeNode id="parentNode"                                     
                                    icon="vpcrf-icon-profile" 
                                    type = "PROFILESET">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ps}" title="#{ps}"
                                          styleClass="vpcrf-txt-400" />
                        </p:treeNode>
                        <p:treeNode id="eventParent" icon="vpcrf-icon-event-parent" type = "PARENT">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ps}" title="#{ps}"
                                          styleClass="vpcrf-txt-400" />
                        </p:treeNode>
                        <p:treeNode id="eventParentHasChild" icon="vpcrf-icon-event-parent" type = "PARENT_HAS_CHILD">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ps}" title="#{ps}"
                                          styleClass="vpcrf-txt-400" />
                        </p:treeNode>
                        <p:treeNode icon="vpcrf-icon-event-child" type = "CHILD">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ps}" title="#{ps}"
                                          styleClass="vpcrf-txt-400" />
                        </p:treeNode>
                    </p:tree>
```

And the controller :

```
    public void onNodeSelectListener(NodeSelectEvent e) {
        try {            
            selectedNode = e.getTreeNode();
            if (selectedNode.getData() instanceof ProfileSetDTO) {
                selectedProfileSet = (ProfileSetDTO) selectedNode.getData();
            } else {
                event = (EventDTO) selectedNode.getData();
                System.out.println(event.getEventName());
            }
            profileSet = null;
            formStatus = Const.CLEAR;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            reportError("msgInfo", "msg.error.unknown");
            logger.error(ex, ex);
        }
    }
```

The problem is ajax event select only fire when I left-click on treenode, when right-click it doesn't work. Is there any way to make it work when I right-click on node ? Any help would be great.

Comment: Please [shorten](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the code. This much code should not be needed to reproduce the phenomenon you are interested in.

Comment: @Tiny I have already edited.

Comment: You make it sound like a bug. The library doesn't purport to offer right-click selection for the treenode, so it's working as designed. If you're looking to simply override the default behaviour, you can sidetrack the stock `onclick` event to function only work when it's a right-click, using Jquery combined somehow with `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selected tree node not set when context menu action is invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270792/selected-tree-node-not-set-when-context-menu-action-is-invoked)

Answer (score 2):

On Primefaces 5.x (I'm using 5.1, but should work also on newer versions), you should be able to solve your issue by adding an ajax event related to contextMenu in the JSF page, as follows:

```
<p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{profileSetEventController.onNodeSelectListener}" update="@([id$=btnPanel]) @([id$=dlgProfileSetEvent])" />
```

I tend to prefer this solution to the one already posted (the one that "overrides" the Primefaces `onRightClick` function) for three reasons.

First, there is no need to modify the Primefaces javascript (what if a newer version changes something about it? It's likely that, in this case, you have to modify your custom script!)

Second, you may want to separate the behavior of the listener `onNodeSelectListener` depending on which click (left or right) is fired by using `e.isContextMenu()` in the backing bean, so the controller may become something like:

```
public void onNodeSelectListener(NodeSelectEvent e) {
    if (e.isContextMenu()) {
      // right click has been fired
    } else {
      // left click has been fired
    }
}
```

The second parameter `true` in `this.selectNode(d, true)` of the Primefaces script `nodeRightClick` serves exactly this purpose. In other words, by using `this.selectNode(d)` (as the overriding script does), it will be not possible to decide whether the listener has been invoked by a left or a right click.

Last, you may want to use a different listener (`onRightClickSelectListener`) for the two events (`select` and `contextMenu`) in the JSF page, as follows:

```
<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{profileSetEventController.onNodeSelectListener}" update="@([id$=btnPanel]) @([id$=dlgProfileSetEvent])" />
<p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{profileSetEventController.onRightClickSelectListener}" update="@([id$=btnPanel]) @([id$=dlgProfileSetEvent])" />
```

and consequentely in the backing bean, as:

```
public void onNodeSelectListener(NodeSelectEvent e) {
   // called when a select event occurs
}

public void onRightClickSelectListener(NodeSelectEvent e) {
  // called when a contextMenu event occurs
}
```

Therefore using a `contextMenu event` only for the right click, instead of using `select event` for both clicks, may be a cleaner approach anyway.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the same [problem I was having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270792/selected-tree-node-not-set-when-context-menu-action-is-invoked). I still don't get why this **is** working in the PrimeFaces showcase, but I was able to fix it by replacing PrimeFaces' `nodeRightClick` handler (JavaScript):

```
PrimeFaces.widget.BaseTree.prototype.nodeRightClick = function(e, a) {
    PrimeFaces.clearSelection();
    if ($(e.target).is(":not(.ui-tree-toggler)")) {
        var d = a.parent(), b = a.hasClass("ui-tree-selectable");
        if (b && this.cfg.selectionMode) {
            var c = this.isNodeSelected(d);
            if (!c) {
                if (this.isCheckboxSelection()) {
                    this.toggleCheckboxNode(d)
                } else {
                    this.unselectAllNodes();
                    // Fixed right click selecting
                    // original code: this.selectNode(d, true)
                    this.selectNode(d); // <-- Fix
                }
            }
            this.fireContextMenuEvent(d)
        }
    }
}
```