# Selected tree node not set when context menu action is invoked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm creating a PrimeFaces (5.3) tree with a context menu. Selected nodes should be stored in `#{myBean.selectedNode}`. When I select a node using the left mouse button the correct node is set. But, when I try to run an action on a node from a context menu, **without selecting it first**, the correct node isn't set (the setter in my bean is not called).

I'm following the [example in the PrimeFaces showcase](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/contextMenu.xhtml), and I suppose I've got everything lined up. What am I doing wrong?

As you can see, in the PrimeFaces showcase you are able to immediately right click a node, click "View", and the growl will display the correct node.

### Bean

I don't think the bean code is relevant (it is `ViewScoped` and there is a `private TreeNode selectedNode` with getter and setter).

Here are the interesting bits though:

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
    MyTreeNode myTreeNode = (MyTreeNode) event.getTreeNode();
    myController.setSelected(myTreeNode.getEntity());
}

public void addChild(String name) {
    MyTreeNode myTreeNode = (MyTreeNode) selectedNode;
    MyTreeNode childNode = myTreeNode.addChild(name);
    myController.setSelected(childNode.getEntity());
    myController.insert();
}
```

### XHTML

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:tree value="#{myBean.root}" var="node"
            id="myTree" dynamic="true"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{myBean.selectedNode}">
        <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed"
                    type="myType">
            <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
        </p:treeNode>
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{myBean.onNodeSelect}" />
    </p:tree>

    <p:contextMenu for="myTree">
        <p:menuitem action="#{myBean.addChild('new')}"
                    value="Add"
                    process="@this"
                    update=":mainForm:myTree"/>
    </p:contextMenu>
</h:form>
```

Comment: your beans is a Session? the field selectedNode is null when the methode addChild is called?

Comment: It is `ViewScoped`. It does work if I first left click the node to make it selected and then right click that node to invoke the context menu action.

Comment: add update="myTree" in <p:ajax> element, add try its work for me, verify you dont has a error javascript in console web browser

Comment: There are no errors in my console. Adding the update does not help. The `selectedNode` setter is not invoked when right clicking a node.

Comment: you can see my answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need the undocumented `contextMenu` Ajax event listener.

See:

- [What event should be used on a p:tree to select a tree node and have a context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792709/what-event-should-be-used-on-a-ptree-to-select-a-tree-node-and-have-a-context-m)

Answer (score 1):

hy,
is a bug in primefaces.
You can fixed this issue by youself. For it you neccessary add verification in the primefaces js file which mouse button has been pressed. You can override file primefaces.js in your project, find first call function selectNode(d) and add follow checking:

```
if (e.which == 1) {
    this.selectNode(d)
    this.cursorNode = d;
}
```

This is part of code you can find then function nodeClick: function (e, a) is called:

```
nodeClick: function (e, a) {
    PrimeFaces.clearSelection();
    if ($(e.target).is(":not(.ui-tree-toggler)")) {
        var d = a.parent();
        if (this.cfg.onNodeClick) {
            this.cfg.onNodeClick.call(this, d)
        }
        if (a.hasClass("ui-tree-selectable") && this.cfg.selectionMode) {
            var c = this.isNodeSelected(d), f = e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey, b = e.shiftKey;
            if (this.isCheckboxSelection()) {
                this.toggleCheckboxNode(d)
            } else {
                if (c && f) {
                    this.unselectNode(d)
                } else {
                    if (this.isSingleSelection() || (this.isMultipleSelection() && !f)) {
                        this.unselectAllNodes()
                    }
                    if (this.isMultipleSelection && b) {
                    } else {
                        if (e.which == 1) {
                             this.selectNode(d);
                             this.cursorNode = d;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to avoid the need to left click first. My code is already working when you left click before opening the context menu. The PF showcase works with only the need of a right click.

Comment: What happens in your case when you don't left click any node, but only right click a node and then click "Add"? Is `setSelectedNode(TreeNode treeNode)` invoked?

Comment: no, the setter is invoked only in left click in one ; (the event is select, this event event is invoked only in select one), you can contact me in private for i help you in live

Comment: Thanks for checking. I modified my question to be more precise on what the problem is and what I'm expecting to happen.

Comment: or dont edite any file js and change your page code for dont use event, without event in p:tree work fine

Comment: Right clicking is handled by `nodeRightClick`. Removing `<p:ajax event="select" .../>` helped, but I need that listener ;-). Thanks for your input!

Comment: ok, if my anser is ok you can accept it, if you need another help say it, tks

Comment: My bad.. removing the select helper did not help :-(. I upvoted your answer. However, the bug and solution (workaround) is in `nodeRightClick`.