# What event should be used on a p:tree to select a tree node and have a context menu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree, contextmenu

I'm creating a PrimeFaces (5.3) tree with a context menu. Selected nodes should be stored in `#{myBean.selectedNode}`. When I select a node using the left mouse button the correct node is set. But, when I try to run an action on a node from a context menu, **without selecting it first**, the correct node isn't set (the setter in my bean is not called).

I'm following the [example in the PrimeFaces showcase](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/contextMenu.xhtml). As you can see, in the PrimeFaces showcase you are able to immediately right click a node, click "View", and the growl will display the correct node.

Here is my setup:

### Bean

It is `ViewScoped` and there is a `private TreeNode selectedNode` with getter and setter.

Here are the interesting bits:

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
    MyTreeNode myTreeNode = (MyTreeNode) event.getTreeNode();
    myController.setSelected(myTreeNode.getEntity());
}

public void addChild(String name) {
    MyTreeNode myTreeNode = (MyTreeNode) selectedNode;
    MyTreeNode childNode = myTreeNode.addChild(name);
    myController.setSelected(childNode.getEntity());
    myController.insert();
}
```

### XHTML

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:tree value="#{myBean.root}" var="node"
            id="myTree" dynamic="true"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{myBean.selectedNode}">
        <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed"
                    type="myType">
            <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
        </p:treeNode>
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{myBean.onNodeSelect}" />
    </p:tree>

    <p:contextMenu for="myTree">
        <p:menuitem action="#{myBean.addChild('new')}"
                    value="Add"
                    process="@this"
                    update=":mainForm:myTree"/>
    </p:contextMenu>
</h:form>
```

I was able to solve this problem by replacing the `PrimeFaces.widget.BaseTree.nodeRightClick` function in JavaScript in order to trigger the `fireNodeSelectEvent` on right click.

```
PrimeFaces.widget.BaseTree.prototype.nodeRightClick = function(e, a) {
    PrimeFaces.clearSelection();
    if ($(e.target).is(":not(.ui-tree-toggler)")) {
        var d = a.parent(), b = a.hasClass("ui-tree-selectable");
        if (b && this.cfg.selectionMode) {
            var c = this.isNodeSelected(d);
            if (!c) {
                if (this.isCheckboxSelection()) {
                    this.toggleCheckboxNode(d)
                } else {
                    this.unselectAllNodes();
                    // Fixed right click selecting
                    // original code: this.selectNode(d, true)
                    this.selectNode(d); // <-- Fix
                }
            }
            this.fireContextMenuEvent(d)
        }
    }
}
```

This seemed like a bug to me, so I created an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1133) on GitHub. This issues was closed as "won't fix" with the comment "Please use contextMenu event".

I've checked the tree and contextMenu section of the documentation twice. What event should be used where? I've [asked](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1133#issuecomment-184109002) the same question at GitHub, but there was no response.

Comment: Did you try the **NON-DOCUMENTED** `<p:ajax event="contextMenu".../>`

Comment: No, I did not. It was not documented ;-) Let me try...

Comment: Works! Listener takes a `NodeSelectEvent` just as the `select` listener does. If you could answer I'll accept and upvote :-)

Comment: will create an answer, but how I found this out is to simple check the source... [java-source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_3/src/main/java-templates/org/primefaces/component/tree/TreeTemplate.java) and [javascript-source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_3/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/tree/tree.js) and search for contextMenu based on the comment made in the [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1133).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading the [issue you reported](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1133), I investigated the code (it **is** open). It seems that `p:tree` has some undocumented events, `contextMenu` being one of them (`dragdrop` being the other).

The [5.3 java-source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_3/src/main/java-templates/org/primefaces/component/tree/TreeTemplate.java) and [5.3 javascript-source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_3/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/tree/tree.js) contains references to a `contextMenu` event, so

```
<p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{myBean.onContextMenu}" />
```

and

```
public void onContextMenu(NodeSelectEvent event) {
    MyTreeNode myTreeNode = (MyTreeNode) event.getTreeNode();
    myController.setSelected(myTreeNode.getEntity());
}
```

will work. Notice that there is no `ContextMenuEvent` but that it accepts/needs a `NodeSelectEvent`

Comment: Cool! `dragdrop` also sounds useful (assuming it will be fired on drop).

Comment: en waarom zitten jullie in Enschede? ;-)

Comment: Enschede is ver weg, maar het is nog lang geen Curaçao hoor.

Comment: Nope, Aruba in juni, vakantie... Maar het ging mij meer om JSF minded bedrijven... nieuwe uitdagingen en zo

Comment: Hey, you are a star and saved my day.

Comment: @Kukeltje Since the documentation is part of the source at GitHub now, I decided to add it: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/4675